# what is the error in my code? I am trying to understand it from 2 days?

Tags: java, arrays, swap

the question is to swap the elements of array
[image]

```java
class Solution {
    void swapKth(int arr[], int n, int k) {
        int n = arr.length();
        arr[k-1]=int temp;
        arr[n-k+1]=arr[k-1];
        arr[n-k+1]=temp;
        int output=0;
        for(swapKth : output){
            return output;
        }
            
    }

}
```

Comment: remove the `int` in `arr[k-1]=int temp;` and for loop syntax is wrong. I would suggest you to learn the syntax of java.

Answer (score 0):

**arr[k-1]=int temp;** is  not a valid assignment. You have syntax error here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

it swaps 3rd element with 6th element in array as your assignment requires.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array_nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(array_nums));
        int x = array_nums[2];
        array_nums[2] = array_nums[array_nums.length - 3];
        array_nums[array_nums.length - 3] = x;
        System.out.println("New array after swaping the first and last elements: " + Arrays.toString(array_nums));
    }

}
```